# Loopback automigrate many to many

Tags: loopbackjs

We're currently trying to write a data sample creation script in order to insert some data into our db to test the API. We have a few many-to-many relations that do not go through another model, so loopback generates the associative tables and their keys (entity 1 fk, entity 2 fk).

Our sample data is stored in JSON files that we later load and pass them to the datasource automigrate function.

The problem we've ran into is that the datasource is not able to migrate data stored in the associative tables (even though they exist in the database) because they do not exist as proper Loopback models.

For example, take the entities Customer and CustomerGroup. A Customer can belong to multiple CustomerGroups and a CustomerGroup can have many Customers, so the following JSON would be used for the CustomerGroupCustomer table resulting from the association:

```
[
    {"CustomerGroupId": "1", "CustomerId": "1"}, 
    {"CustomerGroupId": "2", "CustomerId": "2"},
    {"CustomerGroupId": "1", "CustomerId": "3"}
]
```

Is there a way to migrate this data using the default methods or should we be looking for a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've figured it out! I was using this function to automigrate my tables before:

```
function automigrate(connection, table, data) {
    app.models[table].create(data, function(err, models) {
        if (err) throw err; console.log('|- ' + table);
    });
}
```

It turns out the app object does not know about the many-to-many tables that are being generated by the datasource, whereas the datasource does. So all you need to do is retrieve the models from the datasource object instead of the app:

```
function automigrate(connection, table, data) {
    connection.adapter._models[table].model.create(data, function(err, models) {
        if (err) throw err; console.log('|- ' + table);
    });
}
```